# Python: How can you perform 3 statements together and roll back if one fails?

Tags: python

So I am using shutils to move folders around.

```
def func():
    statement1 (like shutils.move("path", "to_path"))
    statement2
    statement3
```

Right now I have a bug at statement3. I just wonder if it is possible to perform all 3 statements in one go and if 1 fails, all 3 statements will roll back. So I don't need to undo all the operations in statement1 and 2.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you ask for a general solution to this, or for some particular set of functionality? You cannot solve this in general simply because some actions may not be rolled back if performed (e.g. deleting a file). [Here are some possible approaches](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-make-an-undo-function-in-Python) to the idea of _undoability_. For the case of transactions, you can have each statement append a "pending operation" object to a list and execute the operations only on success.

Comment: thanks for the info. I will give transaction a try.  My goal is to move some files and folder, and record some data if the files has been moved.